# Android Studio file names appearing in blue color

Tags: android-studio

Recently I updated my Android Studio to 2.0 preview 4. The files which I visit are marked blue. Is there any significance to this change? How do I change back to white color as it's more readable than the intense blue color.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The blue color refers to git integration. The docs say the files are in blue, that have changed since last check-in.

Most of SO's rules are based on Google SEO, so I have to add here that there are other colors that mean other things. If I do not, someone will come along and say that my answer does not meet guidelines and specifications.

Gray
    Deleted File is scheduled for deletion from the repository.

Blue
    File has changed since the last synchronization.

Green
    File is scheduled for addition to the repository.

Violet
    File is merged by your VCS as a result of an update.

Brown
    File exists locally, but is not in the repository, and is not scheduled for adding.

Olive
    File will be ignored in any VCS operation.

Light brown
    File is modified without checkout. This status is valid for the files under Perforce, ClearCase and VSS.

Red
    During the last update, file was merged with conflicts.

Lilac
    File is deleted locally, but was not scheduled for deletion, and still exists in the CVS repository.

Dark cyan
    The file is taken from a different branch than the whole project. This status is valid for CVS and SVN.

Here is the referenced documentation.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: Android studio is amazing

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since I was new to the android studio interface earlier, I had this stupid doubt. Anyway I figured it out.
All the file names appears in blue color if your project is connected to the github, else they appear white.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the whole theme, that will solve your issue. You can find some themes here: https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes

Comment: What does 'scheduled for deletion from the repository' actually mean? I see gray files which I certainly need, because my app won't build without them, and I haven't asked for them to be deleted. I've tried 'git add', but it doesn't change anything. git commit doesn't report the gray files as untracked.